# How to add Payara 4.1.2.173 to NetBeans 8.1

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, payara

I'm using NetBeans 8.1 (I can't upgrade to 8.2) and have been using Payara 4.1.2.172 without problems. I want to start using Payara 4.1.2.173. As always I've simply downloaded the Payara zip, unzipped it, and tried to add it to NetBeans as a GlassFish server. But when I select the folder where I've unzipped Payara 4.1.2.173, NetBeans tells me it is "Not a valid GlassFish Server installation".

Should I change anything within the Payara 4.1.2.173 folder structure in order to allow NetBeans to recognize it as a GlassFish server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

#### 1. Fix the issue preventing Payara Server being added as GlassFish

The problem here is down to the way that NetBeans detects what version of GlassFish you are trying to add. There is a particular JAR file which contains the version number of GlassFish/Payara Server. The Payara fix for this has been to rename the file as part of the build process, but you can manually rename this yourself to resolve the issue.

In the folder:

```
./glassfish/lib/install/applications/__admingui/WEB-INF/lib/
```

you will find a file with the following name:

```
console-core-4.1.2.173.jar
```

This should be renamed to:

```
console-core-4.1.1.jar
```

#### 2. Add Payara Server using the new Payara Server NetBeans plugins

There are now native plugins in NetBeans for Payara Server. There are 4 available, but all are required. They can be added via NetBeans by using `Tools` -> `Plugins` and searching for Payara.

[More detailed instructions are available in the Payara Server documentation.](https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/ecosystem/netbeans-plugin.html)

Comment: I would have preferred to use the plugin, but that only works with 8.2. Renaming the JAR worked for me.

Comment: @JasperdeVries based on your feedback we have added the Payara plugin as an option for NetBeans 8.1. There is support for both the latest release and the Payara Server 5 snapshots. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks! Just did my first deploy.. everything is working like a charm!