# netbeans 15 and payara 6.2022

Tags: netbeans, payara, netbeans-15

I'm running Netbeans 15 on JDK 17.

I'd like to try Jakarta EE 10 so I've decide to upgrade my App server to Payara 6.2022.1Alpha4.

The app server works and I can deploy my app to it after having updated a lot of libraries. But I can't deploy from Netbeans nor control the server.
I have the Payara plugin installed but it will only accept app server up to 5.2022.3.
It actually finds the 6.2022 install but I cant select it. Clicking the next button doesn't do anything.

How do I add the 6.2022 to my Netbeans environment?

I tried this (with the 6.2022 version):

[How to add Payara 4.1.2.173 to NetBeans 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857067/how-to-add-payara-4-1-2-173-to-netbeans-8-1)

but it didn't work.

Kim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem because [NetBeans 15 was released on August 31, 2022](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/announce-apache-netbeans-15-released), and [Payara 6.2022.1.alpha4 was released on September 20, 2022](https://blog.payara.fish/september-2022-payara-platform-release). Similarly, I'll be amazed if NetBeans 15 supports Jakarta EE 10 [which was released on September 22, 2022](https://blog.payara.fish/whats-new-in-jakarta-ee-10#:%7E:text=Jakarta%20EE%2010%20will%20be,features%20for%20developers%20to%20use.).

In general, it is unreasonable and unrealistic to assume that software which didn't exist when a release of NetBeans was being tested will be supported. And that is doubly true for beta releases, and triply true for alpha releases such as the version of Payara that that you want to use.

Your workaround is to run Payara as a standalone server, and manually deploy your applications to that server. That can become a bit tedious, but it is hardly a showstopper.

NetBeans is on a quarterly release cycle, with NetBeans 16 being released between November 15th - 30th, 2022, and that may provide better support for the most recent releases of Payara, but you will probably find the same problem with all the major IDEs since you are working on the bleeding edge.

Comment: Yes this is my problem. But it's a bit problematic to work with new technology if no tools support them. I can use a standalone Payara for that and that's how I do it now. So only to await for full support later.

Thanks for taking your time to clearify.