# Upgrading to JakartaEE 10 - can't compile because "cannot access javax.faces.event.FacesEvent"

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, payara-micro

My project is this web app: https://nocodefunctions.com, [open sourced here](https://github.com/seinecle/nocodefunctions).

It runs on Payara Community Edition: Payara Micro 5.2022.4

I am moving it to JakartaEE 10 and JSF 3. JakartaEE 10 and Payara 6 (which runs on it) are so recent that NetBeans 15 [does not manage them yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74167393/netbeans-15-and-payara-6-2022).

So I try to develop without NetBeans, directly from the CLI, which is something I am unfamiliar with. I think I can:

1. compile the project with maven (mvn clean install), which creates an single jar of the app
2. then deploy the from the command line to the payara server

I am stuck at step 1:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project jsf-app: Compilation failure:
Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/levallois/open/no code app/webapp/jsf-app/src/main/java/net/clementlevallois/nocodeapp/web/front/importdata/DataImportBean.java:[286,21] cannot access javax.faces.event.FacesEvent
[ERROR]   class file for javax.faces.event.FacesEvent not found
[ERROR] /C:/Users/levallois/open/no code app/webapp/jsf-app/src/main/java/net/clementlevallois/nocodeapp/web/front/functions/TopicsBean.java:[405,37] cannot access javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent
[ERROR]   class file for javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent not found
```

I have found a couple of questions on SO that point to the same error, with answers by @BalusC, but I am still stuck.

- the `pom.xml`:

  4.0.0

  ```
    <groupId>net.clementlevallois.nocodeapp.webfront</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Nocode webapp - jsf app</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>10.0.0</jakartaee>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.faces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.parsson/parsson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.parsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>parsson</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--5Mb-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--809kb-->
  ```

  ```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--8kb-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <release>19</release>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!--    <repositories>
        <repository>  
            <id>prime-repo</id>  
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>-->
  ```

The relevant part of the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd"
    version="2.3">
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of November 2022, Primefaces requires a "jakarta" classifier to make sure it pulls Jakarta dependencies, like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.0</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```